# Cypress undo input text

Tags: cypress

I'd like to write a Cypress test to verify that pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd> on a Mac but ignoring that for now) in an `<input>` text undoes the previously-typed text. For example:

```js
cy.get('input')
  .type('abc')
  .should('have.value', 'abc')
  .type('{ctrl+z}')
  .should('have.value', '');
```

However, the `.type('{ctrl+z}')` doesn't actually seem to trigger the undo. This surprised me because I was able to trigger a custom `keydown` EventListener with the same `.type('{ctrl+z}')`.

I know Cypress [doesn't support](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2386) keyboard shortcuts for copying/pasting, and I'm wondering if I'm running up against a limitation here.

I get that it's usually unnecessary to check something like this, which is default browser behavior and *should* work. But in my case, I want to make sure that my global <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> listener isn't preventing the default undo behavior from firing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events)

```js
cy.get("input").focus();
cy.realType("abc")
cy.get("input").should('have.value', 'abc')    // passes
cy.realPress(["Control", "z"])
cy.get("input").should('have.value', '')       // passes
```

Install with

```js
npm install cypress-real-events
// or
yarn add cypress-real-events
```

Add an import to `cypress/suport/e2e.js`

```js
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

Comment: Oh what a useful library! Does that code work in a test for you? Unfortunately I'm still seeing the same behavior, even with `cy.realPress` :( it would be nice if there were some sort of Cypress sandbox to share examples / test things out.

But having a lot of success in another test of mine using `cy.realClick`!

Comment: Here is a sample repo that illustrates the issue. Any idea what's going wrong? Testing in Chrome/MacOS https://github.com/tuckergordon/cypress-input-text-undo

Comment: I'm not getting it with "Meta", only `cy.realPress(['Control', 'z'])` or `cy.realPress(['Control', 'Z'])`. Maybe it doesn't work on Mac?

Comment: Oh interesting. Yeah with other Cypress commands I have to use `Meta` to get them work on Mac, so figured same applies here. Control doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/5978a6e3efa92b63e8d1ac31eac907d092aaebd3/src/commands/realPress.ts#L40) Meta and control are different - on Windows Meta would be the Windows shortcut key. On a Mac, what modifer key does the user use to undo?

Comment: Meta is the Mac equivalent of windows Control, which is why I was using it. I might open a ticket in the cypress-real-events repo